# phaser game freezes in iphone

Tags: iphone, video, phaser-framework

I am developing a game using phaser js. This game has a tutorial video at the beginning which starts playing automatically when I launch a level. The video plays in iphone's native video player. While the video is playing, if I click the "Done" button that is seen on the top left corner of the video player, the video stops (which is fine) but unfortunately the background tutorial screen is frozen.

I am new to phaser and I don't know how to handle this issue. Would appreciate it if someone could guide me to resolve this issue?

I am pasting a sample link below.

https://phaser.io/examples/v2/video/change-source

This has videos that play as soon as the page is loaded. If you stop the video by tapping the Done button, you will notice that the background will be frozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Need to add event listener**

```
 tutorialVideo.video.addEventListener('webkitendfullscreen', (() => {
    this.game.cache.removeVideo("tutorialVideo");
 }), true);
```

> Try it This Will Work